# How to make 2 bit or more half adder circuit

Tags: logic-gates, adder

I have no idea about electronics, this semester school gave us a strange and confusing lecture about circuits which we shouldn't take because we are no engineer or something close. Question is we should make an 8-bits fulladder and half adder logic circuit on Logisim. Everything is fine until i am stuck with half adder circuit.
I have successfully drawn 8 bit full adder

[image: 8 bit full adder]

I have solved the puzzle which is connecting first Cout with second Cin. But in half adder there is only Cout. I don't know how to connect them each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine two half adders you get the carry-in functionality. Here's a half adder: -

[image]

And here's a full adder: -

[image]

Can you see what has happened i.e. two half adders are combined to make a full adder: -

- Two EXOR gates provide A+B then (A+B)+Cin
- One AND gates provide the intermediary Cout from the direct inputs of A & B
- Another AND provides the intermediary Cout from (A+B)+ Cin
- An OR gate produces the final Cout from the intermediary results.

[image]

So, in effect you have made an 8 bit adder using both "building blocks".

Comment: I went through something like this, is it going good or is there any error?

http://i.imgur.com/JvFHn6B.jpg

Comment: I can't tell because there is no carry in or carry out. As a partial circuit it looks right.

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of an OR gate to combine their carry outputs, two half adders can be combined to make a full adder.